# The Rider's City in Vroengard, is it 'Doru Areaba' or 'Doru Araeba'?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

The Rider's City in Vroengard, its name is 'Dorú *Are***aba**' or 'Dorú *Ara***eba**'?

I have seen both names used in the same paragraph in some places of the wiki, and through the books Paolini uses both. But which is the correct spelling?

Answer (score 2):

### The correct spelling is "Doru Araeba". Christopher Paolini changed it "to remove some inconsistencies in the ancient language".

> *The city on Vroengard is “Doru Araeba”. I took a diacritical mark off the name in the Deluxe Edition. In fact, you may notice that there are a couple of tweaks to words in the Deluxe Edition because I was working on the languages for Book 2 and while developing them further I realized that there was two or three words in Book 1 where I had contradicted myself without realizing it, and the Deluxe Edition was a good opportunity for me to fix that.*
> <sub>[Shurtugal.com Interview, September 2004](https://web.archive.org/web/20041011104524/http://www.shurtugal.com/index.php?id=media/phoneinterview)</sub>

> **Was there an (out of universe) change at some point from Doru Areaba to Doru Araeba? And was there a reason for this change?**
>
> **Christopher Paolini** *It, along with some other words/names, was changed to remove some inconsistencies in the ancient language. As I believe, it was during that process that I realized the mistake that Eragon/I made during the bless the child scene in Book I.*
> <sub>[Twitter, June 2022](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1535313847573094401)</sub>

This change came about while Christopher was working on the Deluxe Edition of *Eragon*, which was to have an expanded guide to languages in the back. As part of writing this Christopher corrected some spellings.

The first book to use the corrected spelling was the Deluxe Edition Eragon in August 2004. This was followed with Eldest in 2005 and all subsequent books.

Answer (score 0):

### The correct spelling is 'Doru Araeba'.

Per the wiki, the spelling ***"Dorú Areaba"*** was present in early printings of Eragon (as well as as the [concept maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmiYk.png) that Paolini drew, and [the map that appeared in the book interior](https://www.paolini.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Alagaesia-for_fan_mail.jpg)). For reasons [best known to Paolini and his editor](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/1535313847573094401), this original spelling seems to have been replaced with "***Doru Araeba***" from *The Eldest* onward (note the spelling change as well as the loss of the acute symbol over the u).

This change has also been made to subsequent printings of Eragon, both in the novel text and [the interior map](https://www.paolini.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/IMG_6167-modifiedweb.jpg), retconning the earlier spelling out of existence.

> The spelling Doru Araeba is used from Eldest onwards as well as in
> reprints and collectable editions of Eragon, while in initial
> printings of Eragon and some translations of the rest of the series
> the city is spelled Dorú Areaba or Doru Areaba
>
> <sub><sup>[Doru Araebe: Inheriwiki](https://inheritance.fandom.com/wiki/Doru_Araeba)</sup></sub>